# Remove multiple lines from multiple files multiple times

Tags: regex, perl

I have several files (`*.txt`) that I need to remove lines from. The files look like this:

```
This is a line to keep.
keep me too
START
some stuff to remove
other to remove
END
keep me!
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
This is a line to keep.
keep me too
keep me!
```

I've gotten this far:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/#START.*?END/ /s' file.txt
```

Which will remove the first instance of that from `file.txt`, but I can't figure out how to remove all instances from `file.txt` (and then how to apply this to all `*.txt` files?)

Comment: This is simple, but does it have to be a one-liner? Are the files supposed to be changed in place, or new ones written, or do you want just one big file as output?

Comment: Thanks @zdim No, it doesn't have to be a one-liner. I don't care whether they're changed in place or not, and I want individual files as output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you show works for the first instance, all you should need to add is the `/g` flag to do all instances, and a shell glob to pick out all .txt files:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/#START.*?END/ /gs' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried adding the `/g` flag before but it just deleted everything in all the files. This works, though, so I must've done something wrong before. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be right for the *[flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( <DATA> ) {
    print unless (/^START/ .. /^END/);
}

__DATA__
This is a line to keep.
keep me too
START
some stuff to remove
other to remove
END
keep me!
```

Output:

```
This is a line to keep.
keep me too
keep me!
```

It can also be written as a one-liner:

```
perl -n -e 'print unless (/^START/ .. /^END/);' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or, to edit the files in-place:

```
perl -n -i -e 'print unless (/^START/ .. /^END/);' *.txt
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're right. Thank you. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bookkeeping thing to take care of here is opening and writing of individual files. The processing itself is handled by the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = @ARGV;

my ($fh_in, $fh_out);

foreach my $file (@files) 
{
    my $outfile = "new_$file";

    open $fh_in, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    open $fh_out, '>', $outfile  or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

    print "Processing $file, writing to $outfile.\n";

    while (<$fh_in>) {
        print $fh_out $_ if not /^START$/ .. /^END$/;
    }
}
```

This is invoked as `script.pl file-list`.

Since we use the same filehandle for reading (and the same one for writing), when a new file is opened the previous one is closed, see [`perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) and [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). So we don't have to [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)

> You don't have to close FILEHANDLE if you are immediately going to do another open on it, because open closes it for you. (See open.)

I name the new files as `new_$file`, just to provide a working sample. You could, for example, rename the old one to `$file.orig` and new one to `$file` instead, after the `while` loop. I'd use functions from the core [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module for this. In this case we do need to close files explicitly first.